# Find product's frequency in this CashRegister class

Tags: ruby, algorithm, oop, enumerable, ruby-hash

I have 3 simple classes CashRegister, Bill and Position. A CashRegister is composed of Bill objects and a Bill object is composed of Position objects. They're implemented as followed

```
class CashRegister
  def initialize
    @bills = []
  end

  def product_frequency
    #???
  end

  def << bill
    @bills << bill
    self
  end
end

class Bill
  attr_reader :positions,:nr
  protected :positions

  def initialize(nr)
    @nr = nr
    @positions = []
  end

  def << pos
    @positions << pos
    self
  end
end

class Position
  attr_reader :product,:quantity,:price
  def initialize(product,quantity,single_price)
    @product = product
    @quantity = quantity
    @price = single_price * quantity
  end
end
```

I want to write a **product_frequency** method that calculates how often a product is bought in the CashRegister. This method returns a hash as a result, with the product as key, and the frequency as value. 
An example would be:

```
pos1 = Position.new('Chicken',    5,      12)
pos2 = Position.new('Soup',       6,      24)
pos3 = Position.new('Burger',     3,      19)
pos4 = Position.new('Chicken',    2,      12)
pos5 = Position.new('Soup',       8,      24)
pos6 = Position.new('Burger',     9,      19)

bill1 = Bill.new(1) << pos1 << pos2 << pos3     #Chicken: 5;Soup: 6;Burger: 3
bill2 = Bill.new(2) << pos4 << pos3 << pos2     #Chicken: 2;Soup: 6;Burger: 3
bill3 = Bill.new(3) << pos6 << pos6 << pos6     #Chicken: 0;Soup: 0;Burger: 27
bill4 = Bill.new(4) << pos4 << pos5 << pos4     #Chicken: 4;Soup: 8;Burger: 0

my_cash_register = CashRegister.new << bill1 << bill2 << bill3 << bill4
my_cash_register.product_frequency    #{'Chicken' => 11, 'Soup' => 20, 'Burger' => 33}
```

How can I accomplish that result?

Comment: What have you tried so far?Please show your code. What is your problem?

Comment: @spickermann This comes from a huge exercise I have. I tried to minimize the problem as much as I could. The answer from Bartosz works, but only when the **positions** method of class Bill isn't **protected**. Is there anyway to achieve it with **positions** still **protected**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken mostly from the solution of Bartosz Bonisławski. But since `positionen` in `bill` is `protected`, we first have to make it accessible by defining an `each` function in `Bill` that takes in a block and applies it to every `position` of `positions`. We also do the same for `CashRegister`.

```
class CashRegister
  def initialize
    @bills = []
  end

  def each(&block)
    @bills.each(&block)
  end

  def product_frequency
    result = {} 
    each { |bill| 
      bill.each { |position| 
        result[position.product] ||= 0 
        result[position.product] += position.quantity 
      } 
    } 
    result 
  end

  def << bill
    @bills << bill
    self
  end
end

class Bill
  attr_reader :positions,:nr
  protected :positions

  def initialize(nr)
    @nr = nr
    @positions = []
  end

  def each(&block)
    @positions.each(&block)
  end

  def << pos
    @positions << pos
    self
  end
end

class Position
  attr_reader :product,:quantity,:price
  def initialize(product,quantity,single_price)
    @product = product
    @quantity = quantity
    @price = single_price * quantity
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to count how many times each product was bought, then here it is:

```
  def product_frequency
    product_frequency = {}
    @bills.each do |bill|
      bill.positionen.each do |position|
        @product_frequency[position.product] ||= 0
        @product_frequency[position.product] += position.quantity
      end
    end
    product_frequency
  end
```

It's just one way of doing it. Code is pretty easy, so I think you can figure how it works

Comment: This works great only if the **positions** method of class Bill isn't protected.

Answer (score 0):

You could define `#frequency` for each nested class and then recursively collect hashes.

```
class Hash
  def additive_merge!(hash)
    hash.each { |k,v| self[k] ? self[k] += v : self[k] = v }
    self
  end
end

class CashRegister
  def initialize
    @bills = []
  end

  def product_frequency
   @bills.map(&:frequency).reduce(&:additive_merge!)
  end

  def << bill
   @bills << bill
   self
  end
end

class Bill
  attr_reader :positionen,:nr
  protected :positionen

  def initialize(nr)
    @nr = nr
    @positions = []
  end

  def << pos
   @positions << pos
   self
  end

  def frequency
    @positions.map(&:frequency).reduce(&:additive_merge!)
  end
end

class Position
  attr_reader :product,:quantity,:price

  def initialize(product,quantity,single_price)
    @product = product
    @quantity = quantity
    @price = single_price * quantity
  end

  def frequency
    { product => quantity }
  end
end
```